# Cant load a Geojson file as path in Gmaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

I am attempting to create a polygon from a GeoJson file and trigger an alert if a marker leaves the area. I am following gmap tutorials and alot of the code i see is as follows:

```
var path = [[-12.040397656836609,-77.03373871559225], 
[-12.040248585302038,-77.03993927003302], [-12.050047116528843,-
77.02448169303511], [-12.044804866577001,-77.02154422636042]];

 polygon = map.drawPolygon({
 paths: path,
 strokeColor: '#BBD8E9',
 strokeOpacity: 1,
 strokeWeight: 3,
 fillColor: '#BBD8E9',
 fillOpacity: 0.6
 });

map.addMarker({
lat: -12.043333,
lng: -77.028333,
draggable: true,
fences: [polygon],
outside: function(marker, fence) {
alert('This marker has been moved outside of its fence');
 }
});
```

I am trying to use data from a GeoJson file as the path.
I have tried certain lines of code such as:

```
 var path = map.data.loadGeoJson("./js/area.geojson");
```

But its like the data isnt loading. I am very new to this and would appreciate any feedback, thank you

Updated code:

```
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: {lat: 53.28, lng: -7.48},
     zoom: 10,
    });

    var path = map.data.loadGeoJson("./js/area.geojson");

    polygon = map.drawPolygon({
    paths: path,
    useGeoJSON: true,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#BBD8E9',
    fillOpacity: 0.6
  });;

  map.addMarker({
    lat: 53.28,
    lng: -7.48,
    draggable: true,
    fences: [polygon],
    outside: function(m, f){
      alert('This marker has been moved outside of its fence');
    }
  });


  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing,places&amp;language=en&key=AIzaSyBDv0PtStQ3dOIyBcqUSxChO7TB-CqdeXY&callback=initMap">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gmaps.js"></script>
```

error:

```
typeError: map.drawPolygon is not a function[Learn More]

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///C:/geo_fencing%20project  
/js/area.geojson
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

The coordinates in the geojson file are creating a border on the map, and i have used the geojson file in other tests and it is fine. But a marker is not appearing.

Comment: What errors do you get?  What is the data in the GeoJson file?  Is it valid?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Does [GMaps](https://github.com/hpneo/gmaps) support the Google Maps API  v3 `DataLayer`?

Comment: HI. Now the border is loading onto the map, so i have a geofenced area, but the error i am getting is TypeError: map.drawPolygon is not a function.

Comment: Please post the updated code in your question.

Comment: Hi @geocodezip. I have updated the question.

Comment: Your map is now a `google.maps.Map` that doesn't have a `drawPolygon` method.

Comment: Oh ok, so i need to replace that section with    new GMaps({...  ?